# How do I have the Python program user choose the list to pull from?

Tags: python

So I have:

```
List = ["A", "B"]

List2 = ["C", "D"]

answer = input("Which list?")

print()
```

and I want it to print item 0 of whichever list I specify.

I've only just started Python so there might be a way that I'm unaware of but I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: to get item 0 of any list, you can give `List[0]` or `List2[0]`. Since you have two lists, what would the response from the user? `List` / `List1` or `1` or `2` ? Based on that, you can use an if statement to print one of the two. Alternate, you can create a function and print the first item from that list.

Comment: I want the user to say "List" and get A printed, or say "List2" and get C printed. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a really simple answer:

```
list1 = ["A", "B"]
list2 = ["C", "D"]

answer = input("Which list?").strip()

if answer == '1':
    print(list1[0])
elif answer == '2':
    print(list2[0])
else:
    print("invalid list number: " + answer)
```

If you want an arbitrary number of named lists, then you can do this...

```
lists = {
    'list1': ["A", "B"],
    'list2': ["C", "D"]
}

answer = input("Which list?").strip()

if answer in lists:
    print(lists[answer][0])
else:
    print("no list named " + answer)
```

Comment: starswith or endswith?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use a dictionary

```
l = {"list":[1, 2, 3],
  "list2":[7, 8, 9]}
l[input("Enter list to choose from. list or list2")][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if you understand the way this code works.

## with function option:

In this code, we have defined a function that takes in a list, then prints the first element of the list.

This code also has a if statement and passes the correct list to the function.

```
def print_list(alist):
    print (alist[0])

List1 = ["A", "B"]

List2 = ["C", "D"]

answer = input("Which list?")

if answer == 'List1':
    print_list(List1)
elif answer == 'List2':
    print_list(List2)
else:
    print ('Sorry wrong choice')
```

## without function option:

In this option, we check for the value entered by the user, then print the first element based on the option.

```
List1 = ["A", "B"]

List2 = ["C", "D"]

answer = input("Which list?")

if answer == 'List1':
    print (List1[0])
elif answer == 'List2':
    print (List2[0])
else:
    print ('Sorry wrong choice')
```